# Overloading assignment operator for type deduction

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-literals

Here's the ideone code: http://ideone.com/Qp8Eqg

My question is, is it possible to force a conversion based on the lvalue alone? For example,

```cpp
[Seconds] s = 2_h + 60_s;
cout <<s.getSeconds()<<endl;
```

Obviously, I would have to write something like 2_h.toSeconds(), but that would be too verbose and doesn't achieve the idea.

Comment: Do you mean `Seconds s = 2_h + 60_s;`? Or even more likely: `Seconds s = 2_h;`?

Comment: `2_h.toSeconds()` is invalid. You can write `2_h .toSeconds()` to make it valid, though. Alternatively, do `(2_h).toSeconds()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow this (which is more likely your question than what you wrote, correct me if I'm wrong):

```
Seconds s = 2_h;
```

the following would work: Add `operator Seconds() const` to class `Hours`:

```
class Hours {
    unsigned long long _hours;
public:
    Hours(unsigned long long hours) : _hours(hours) { }

    operator Seconds() const;

    unsigned long long getHours() const {
        return this->_hours;
    }
};
```

and define it *after* class `Seconds`:

```
Hours::operator Seconds() const { return this->_hours * 3600; }
```

Answer (score 1):

As already noted in the answer given you need to have the `operator Seconds ()` implemented to allow automatic conversion from `Hours` to `Seconds`. With this operator in place you can also simplify `operator+`. And to improve run-time you can also throw in some `constexpr` to have values evaluated at compile time.

```
#include <iostream>

class Seconds {
    public:
        constexpr Seconds(const Seconds& other) : seconds_(other.seconds_) {}
        constexpr Seconds(unsigned long long seconds) : seconds_(seconds) {}

        Seconds& operator=(const Seconds& other) {
            seconds_  = other.seconds_;
            return *this;
        }

        constexpr unsigned long long value() const {
            return this->seconds_;
        }

    private:
        unsigned long long seconds_;
};


class Hours {
    public:
        constexpr Hours(const Hours& other) : hours_(other.hours_) {}
        constexpr Hours(unsigned long long hours) : hours_(hours) {}

        Hours& operator=(const Hours& other) {
            hours_ = other.hours_;
            return *this;
        }

        unsigned long long value() const {
            return this->hours_;
        }

        operator Seconds () const { return Seconds(hours_*60*60); }
    private:
        unsigned long long hours_;
};


constexpr Seconds operator+(const Seconds& lhs, const Seconds& rhs) 
{
    return Seconds(lhs.value()+rhs.value());
}

constexpr Hours operator "" _h(unsigned long long hours) {
    return Hours(hours);
}

constexpr Seconds operator "" _s(unsigned long long seconds) {
    return Seconds(seconds);
}


int main() {
    using namespace std;

    Seconds s = 1_h + 10_s;
    cout <<s.value()<<endl;
    s = 2_h + 60_s;
    cout <<s.value()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but you made one small typo. It should be lhs.value()+rhs.value().