# creating new operator in c++ with/without preprocessors

Tags: c++

I am trying to spend my free time with something useful.
I am writing some codes based on linear algebra, defining Rn vectors, matrices and operations.

When I was writing the code for computing cross product between two R3 vectors, I faced a possibility of creating a new operator called `x`, then I could use `u x v` instead of `u.vectorial(v);`.

I'm telling you this because I read somethings and saw that with preprocessors I could do something like what I want. So, is there a way so I could do this?

Comment: Whether you can doesn't matter. What matters is whether you *should*. Should you? No.

Comment: Knew I'd gotten the idea somewhere.  Well, looks like it's already described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632217/defining-new-infix-operators

Comment: w = vector_product(u, v) - nice, simple and readable (avoid horseplay)

Answer (score 7):

This is not going to end well.  C++ itself provides no support for creating new operators, only providing custom per-type behavior for the existing ones.  And the preprocessor does nothing per-type, nor has any support for infix notation.

I sure wouldn't try to use single-letter operators, since they'll get replaced *everywhere* in your program.

To make something like `u cross v` work, you could

```
#define cross * cross_product_helper() *
```

And then use some techniques from expression trees -- the `operator*(vec, cross_product_helper)` returns a helper type that holds the vector and knows it wants to do cross product, the second use of `*` actually does the multiply.

On the other hand, would it be so bad to have the code written like:

```
u *cross* v
```

Where `cross` is a pre-defined, properly scoped variable of type `cross_product_helper`?  (And of course you could have similar `dot` and `element` defined with unique types to make `u *cross* v`, `u *dot* v`, and `u *element* v` (and `u /element/ v`) all work and return different types.

Note that I've chosen `operator*` as the foundation for `*cross*`, as opposed to `+cross+` or `^cross^`, because it has the precedence and other grammatical properties associated with products.

Comment: +1 for something I never would have thought of, though at this point I personally think `cross(u, v)`, `dot(u, v)`, etc. is clearer, cleaner, and easier to debug than this magic.

Comment: @Cornstalks: But `dot(cross(u, v) * 2, element_product(element_product(x, y), z))` is not cleaner than `2 * (u *cross* v) *dot* (x *element* y *element* z)`

Comment: Touché, you win again.

Comment: And it isn't hard for `dot` to both support `dot(x,y)` and `x *dot* y`.

Comment: @Yakk: Very good point.  Just give `dot_product_helper` an `operator()(vec, vec)`.

Comment: Nifty solution. Just to expand this, if you continue the lazy combine into some sort of expression statement, and don't reduce back to matrix until you have to (aka `other_expression operator*(cross_product_helper,matrix)` it is theoretically possible to reduce the total number of calculations and speed up the code by reducing to a triple cross product or higher. Cool.

Comment: Was on Class, but i'll look into this and i think i'll gonna need some explanation too. :v

Answer (score 0):

Do not use preprocessors. They are bad. Best to avoid. You should look into overloading operators. http://www.functionx.com/cpp/Lesson25.htm

Comment: `operator*` is probably reserved for scalar product

Comment: Why avoid them? Could you explain?