# Infix operator to check membership in a fixed set?

Tags: c++, set, operator-overloading, membership, infix-operator

Suppose I have a (compile-time) fixed set of values from a certain type, e.g. `foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3`, `foo4` of type `Foo`. At runtime, I have a variable `my_foo` of type `Foo`, and I want to be able to check whether it is one of my foo's - not by individual independent check. So, I basically want to be able to write something like:

```
if ( my_foo is_in {foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4} ) do_stuff();
```

can I implement such an `is_in`  operator (could be called something else, e.g. `member_of`, `in`, `found_in` or whatever). Is this possible?

Comment: You mean [like this](https://github.com/klmr/named-operator) (i.e. `my_foo <in> {foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4}`)?

Comment: C++ does not support custom operators.

Comment: @Quimby Well check the link I posted and be amazed.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I am amazed, still, it is not a custom operator any more than `std::boolalpha` is. But I think it's very cool and like this "abuse", I just wanted to make the point clear for OP. BTW, it likely won't play nicely with clang-format's spacing rule which is unfortunate, or have you tested it?

Comment: @Quimby You can probably create a custom spacing rule for it but I’ve never used linters in C++ so I have no experience with this. Anyway, I’m confident that einpoklum is aware that C++ doesn’t support custom operators, so I think they were after a similar hack.

Comment: @Quimby: With just tiny bit of macro work, it [can support them just fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70328397/1593077)...

Comment: @KonradRudolph: That's very nice, but not quite all the way there syntax-wise. You can get proper syntax like in my question; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70328397/1593077). On the other hand - I use a macro, and you might not be using one (or are you?)

Comment: @einpoklum I’m not against macro use, but unhygienic, unscoped macros are a pretty big no-no, indeed. And I think you’ll agree that the macro `MYLIBNAME_IS_ONE_OF` is completely unusable, especially compared to `<in>`.